# WPF Image width and height ratio

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have listview of images in different resolution. I would like to do something that width of picture will be auto and heigth will be 75% or something of width. Images will be autoscale to this resolution.

Comment: Sounds like a quickie for something like `ViewBox` and `ClipToBounds` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `IMultivalueConverter` instance, which would accept the `ActualWidth` value of your `ListView`, and the image itself.
The converter would manipulate the `Bitmap` and it could be rendered with the desired parameters.